# documents are not available after successfully uploaded to custom translator

Tags: microsoft-translator

I uploaded a zip that contains tmx files and it uploaded it successfully. I can see them in Upload History. But when I try to build a model, it's not listed in the data. I am not sure what went wrong.  I see all other documents.

thanks,
--Yoshi

Answer (score 0):

--Update 3/11/2019--

We've resolved the issue with TMX files uploaded within a ZIP.

--Original answer 3/8/2019--

We're investigating this issue right now. The issue is only with TMX files that are uploaded as part of a ZIP file, so for now a workaround is to upload TMX files separately. Make sure when uploading the TMX separately to check the "Override document if it exists" check box. We'll update this thread when we've shipped a fix.